# Replace Query not working when it's having a quote

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query: it's giving me following error:
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

```
update table1 
set    description = replace(description,'[imp]','if([type]='A',[count],0)'
where  description like '%[imp]%';
```

I tried the following too, same error prevails:

```
update table1 
set    description = replace(description,'[imp]','if([type]=''A'',[count],0)'
where  description like '%[imp]%';
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Well the error is correct... you're missing a right parenthesis. You have a REPLACE( and an IF( but you have only closed one of them.

Comment: Your second version, with escaped quotes should work, but you're missing a closing parenthesis - which the ORA-00907 is telling you - immediately before the `where`...

Comment: Thanks! That works! It's the replace ) that was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table1 
set    description = replace(description,'[imp]','if([type]=''A'',[count],0)')
where  description like '%[imp]%';
```

Added a right parenthesis to resolve your error. Otherwise, your query should be good.